# Need help with z-transform question.

Tags: z-transform

The question is to find the z-transform of $$ x(n) = 3n\cdot u(n-2)$$

So far I have seen a question asking to find z-transformation of $x(n)=3^n u(n-2)$ and I know the solution. Howver for the sequence $ x(n) = 3n\cdot u(n-2)$ , I am having a hardtime finding the z-transform. Is this a typo? If not, please provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let us do it step-by-step:

z-transform of $u(n)$:
$$u(n)\to \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}$$

Then for $u(n-2)$ we use time-shifting property:

$$u(n-2)\to z^{-2}\,\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}=\frac{z^{-2}}{1-z^{-1}}$$

Now it's time to multiply $n$ and use differentiation in z-domain property:

$$nu(n-2)\to -z\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{z^{-2}}{1-z^{-1}}\right)$$

And of course there is a $3$ to be multiplied:

$$3nu(n-2)\to -3z\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{z^{-2}}{1-z^{-1}}\right)$$

and by simplifying the right-hand-side we get:

$$\mathcal{Z}(3nu(n-2))=3\,\frac{2z^{-2}-z^{-3}}{(1-z^{-1})^2}$$